# Function sometimes requires a double click to work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 functions the same as the one below. ShowAction2(), ShowAction3() and ShowAction4(). Each function is responsible for displaying a DIV, hiding other DIVs and adding and removing classes.

It then removes the showAction() function and adds a new function, gogo(). which reverses the whole process if the function is called a second time.

```
  $("#clickDiv").click(function showAction(){
     $("#infDivOne").show();
     $("#infDivTwo, #infDivThree, #infDivFour").hide();
     $(".goActive2, .goActive3, .goActive4").removeClass('glow');
     $("#clickDiv2, #clickDiv3, #clickDiv4").removeClass('rotated');
     $("#clickDiv").addClass('rotated');
     $(".goActive").addClass('glow');
     $("#clickDiv").off('click');

     $("#clickDiv").on('click', function gogo(){
        $("#infDivOne").hide();
        $(".goActive").removeClass('glow');
        $("#clickDiv").removeClass('rotated');
        $("#clickDiv").off('click');
        $("#clickDiv").on('click',showAction);
    });
  });
```

I'm sure there are better ways to achieve a similar result but right now, this is kind of working. The only problem is, sometimes I have to double click the button for the function to be called.

I will eventually replace the whole function, but could anyone possibly point out why it requires a double click sometimes and a single click other times?

(And I apologise in advance to anyone who tries to read through this jibberish.)

Comment: click event inside a click event is probably the main reason.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve assigning two click events to same id `clickDiv`? and click event inside click event?

Comment: The functionality here seems to loosely mimic the old .toggle(fn,fn) method, id' suggest looking at the toggleClass method.

Comment: Basically, the button does one thing, and then I want it to reverse everything it has done on the second click. So someone can toggle the effects on and off.

Comment: You need the old deprecated toggle function, see this for details http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you put an attribute on $("#clickDiv") to manage actual step ?

```
$("#clickDiv").on("click",function showAction(){
    var _step = $(this).attr("step");
    switch(_step){
         case 1:
         case 2:
    }
});
```

Good Lucky.

Comment: Why not use a `data-*` attribute here?

Comment: yeah, go by person, "data-step", "data-actual" :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the element on the click to tell which action happened then depending on the classes present do one thing or the other.

```
 $("#clickDiv").click(function showAction(){
     var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass("secondClick"))
    {
        showAction(this);
        $this.removeClass("secondClick");
    }
    else if($this.hasClass("firstClick"))
    {
        $("#infDivOne").hide();
        $(".goActive").removeClass('glow');
        $("#clickDiv").removeClass('rotated');
        $this.removeClass("firstClick").addClass("secondClick");
    }
    else{
       $this.addClass("firstClick");
       $("#infDivOne").show();
       $("#infDivTwo, #infDivThree, #infDivFour").hide();
       $(".goActive2, .goActive3, .goActive4").removeClass('glow');
       $("#clickDiv2, #clickDiv3, #clickDiv4").removeClass('rotated');
       $("#clickDiv").addClass('rotated');
       $(".goActive").addClass('glow');
    }

  });
```

Comment: You could use the existing rotated class for this.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$("#clickDiv").click(function() {
    if($("infDivOne").is(":visible")) {
        // This div is visible, so toggle the effects off
    }
    else {
        // This div isn't visible, so toggle the effects on
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set them up and toggle them seems like an easier method.  I might have the initial states/classes inverse but this should toggle stuff.

```
$("#infDivOne").hide();
$("#infDivTwo, #infDivThree, #infDivFour").show();
$(".goActive2, .goActive3, .goActive4").addClass('glow');
$("#clickDiv2, #clickDiv3, #clickDiv4").addClass('rotated');

$("#clickDiv").click(function () {
    $("#infDivOne, #infDivTwo, #infDivThree, #infDivFour").toggle();
    $(".goActive, .goActive2, .goActive3, .goActive4").toggleClass('glow');
    $("#clickDiv, #clickDiv2, #clickDiv3, #clickDiv4").toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

NOW if you want all of them to toggle, just do:

```
$("#clickDiv, #clickDiv2, #clickDiv3, #clickDiv4").click(function () {
    $("#infDivOne, #infDivTwo, #infDivThree, #infDivFour").toggle();
    $(".goActive, .goActive2, .goActive3, .goActive4").toggleClass('glow');
    $("#clickDiv, #clickDiv2, #clickDiv3, #clickDiv4").toggleClass('rotated');
    $("#clickDiv").toggleClass('rotated');
    $(".goActive").toggleClass('glow');
});
```

---

EDIT: Given all your comments, I believe this is MUCH more easily done with classes:

Markup:

```
<div id="clickDiv1" class="clickDiv">One click</div>
<div id="clickDiv2" class="clickDiv">Two click</div>
<div id="clickDiv3" class="clickDiv">Three click</div>
<div id="clickDiv4" class="clickDiv">Four click</div>
<div id="infDivOne" class="InfoDiv">Info 1</div>
<div id="infDivTwo" class="InfoDiv">Info 2</div>
<div id="infDivThree" class="InfoDiv">Info 3</div>
<div id="infDivFour" class="InfoDiv">Info 4</div>
<div id="goActive">ACTIVE: <span class="goActive">One</span>
 <span class="goActive">Two</span>
 <span class="goActive">Three</span>
 <span class="goActive">Four</span>
</div>
```

Code:

```
// event handler
$(".clickDiv").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.InfoDiv').hide().eq(index).show();
    $('.goActive').removeClass('glow').eq(index).addClass('glow');
    $('.clickDiv').removeClass('rotated').eq(index).addClass('rotated');
});
// setup first one as active
$(".clickDiv").eq(0).trigger('click');
```

Fiddle to show in action: http://jsfiddle.net/MMerB/

Comment: Well heres the problem, when the first clickDiv is clicked, #infoDivOne appears and all other infoDivs disappear. And similarly, when clickDiv2 is clicked, infoDivTwo appears and all other infoDivs disappear. I really appreciate the help but, unless I'm understanding it wrong, your method wont accomplish this.

Comment: @Daft - I added an example using classes which I believe will be much more useful here given all your comments - I implied some things here from that.